# How to store a Jena Model in a SDB database?

Tags: database, jena

I've an ontology create that I've populate with individuals. Actually my ontology is an `OntModel` object let say `model`. How can I store all Individuals of my model in a `SDB` database. All examples that I've seen up to now only address the problem of reading data from a SDB database. But first of all, How have they been put there !

thanks for any reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open up a `Model` backed by an SDB store, it's a normal Jena model and the standard techniques to read a file into the model and to assert triples into the model will automatically write through to the underlying relational database. The [documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/javaapi.html#loading-data) confirms this.

You can also load data directly into an SDB store using the [command line utilities](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/commands.html#loading-data).